# Solve $\sin z = 2$

Tags: complex-analysis

> How to solve $\sin(z) = 2$,where $z$ is a complex number.

Another approach I tried:

$$\sin z=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{iz}-e^{-iz}\right)=2$$

$$e^{iz}-e^{-iz}=4i$$

Let $x=e^{iz}$ so that $x^2-4ix-1=0$. Then, I would use the quadratic formula to solve would this be correct?

Comment: It's a good start. Now note that $a$ is real, so you must have $\cos(x)\sinh(y) = 0$. Which options for $x$ and $y$ does that give you?

Comment: @robotgirl21 Please do not change radically your question like this, after edition answers do not correspond. If you need to show two approaches then just append to the existing text.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing your answer, we have now $\sin x\cosh y=a$ and $\cos x\sinh y=0.$ From the second equation $\cos x=0$ or $\sinh y=0.$ If $\cos x=0$ then $x=\pi/2(2n+1)$. But the first equation then gives that $\cosh y=a$ which is not possible because $\cosh y\geq1.$ Hence $\sinh y=0$ and therefore $y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative: write $w:=\exp(iz)$ so $w^2-2iaw-1=0$, with roots $w=ia\pm\sqrt{1-a^2}$. Since the surd is real, $|w|^2=a^2+1-a^2=1$, so $z\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Note
$$2=\sin z= \cos(2\pi k +\frac\pi2 -z)
= \cosh[i(2\pi k +\frac\pi2 -z)]
$$
which leads to $i(2\pi k +\frac\pi2 -z)=\pm \cosh^{-1} 2$
and the solutions
$$z= 2\pi k +\frac\pi2\pm i \cosh^{-1} 2$$